# Logging configuration with file appenders and stdout in grails

Tags: grails, log4j

I have a configuration error in my grails application that's causing my appenders to send output to the wrong place, or not at all. There seem to be a number of questions regarding duplicate logging but I have been unable to apply any of the answers to my situation.

Here is my logging config snippet:

```
log4j = {

        appenders {
                // appender for usage tracking
                appender new org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender(
                        name:"usageAppender",
                        maxFileSize:"1000KB",
                        maxBackupIndex: 10000,
                        file: "/var/log/tomcat6/app/usage.log",
                        layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{DATE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n')
                )
                appender new org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender(
                        name:"application",
                        maxFileSize:"1000KB",
                        maxBackupIndex: 10000,
                        file:"/var/log/tomcat6/app/application.log",
                        layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{DATE} %8X{memoryused} %5p %t %c{1}:%L %X{username} %X{request} - %m%n')
                )
                console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{DATE} %8X{memoryused} %5p %t %c{1}:%L %X{username} %X{request} - %m%n')
        }
        root {
                // also tried error 'stdout'
                error  'application'
        }

        error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
                   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
                   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
                   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
                   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
                   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
                   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
                   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
                   'org.springframework',
                   'org.hibernate'

        info 'usageAppender':'usage.gui'
}
```

When my program runs, output appears in `catalina.out`, in `usage.log` and in `application.log`. Output sent directly to stdout (bypassing log4j) appears in catalina.out

If I set

```
 info additivity: false 'usageAppender': 'usage.gui'
```

Then nothing is logged to either file appender, but stdout still goes into catalina.out (bypassing log4j).

I would like the output from the 'usage.gui' logger to go to the `usage.log` file, output from all other logging to go to the `application.log` file, and all print statement output to go to  `catalina.out`. I don't want redundant logging. How do I configure this?

*UPDATE*
In answer to @dmahapatro's question, logging in the application is done either with standard grails logging

```
log.trace('some event');
```

or with a custom logger created like this:

```
def usageLog
public UsageService() {
    usageLog = Logger.getLogger("usage.gui")
}
```

and used by calling this function:

```
protected void writeRecord(String topicId, String user, Long id, Long priorId, Long clientTime, String component, String action, String otherData) {
    String msg = "$topicId\t$user\t$id\t$priorId\t$clientTime\t$component\t$action\t$otherData"
    usageLog.info(msg)
}
```

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16898898/2051952) help?

Comment: When I set `additivity: false` on the `usageAppender`, it stops working. I would like all my other log4j output to go to the application.log file, but I am not sure how to specify that. I thought that's what my `root { error 'application' }` line was doing.

Comment: Stress on the setup shown in the question [I provided by the link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16894504/2051952) earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this setting.

- Keep `stdout` at root (if needed change the level to `info`/`debug`/`all`). Set additivity to `false` in order to restrict console logs getting added to `usage` or `application` appender.
- Other appenders inherit from `root`, set `additivity` `false` for `application` and `usage` to restrict console logging.
- Use `grails.app` against `application` to log all application related logs in `application.log`.

Like:

```
root {
         error 'stdout'
         additivity: false
     }

info usageAppender: 'usage.gui'
        additivity: false

info application: 'grails.app'
       additivity: false
```

Note:-
Logs at the different logging level will not work for same package structure. For example:

```
info usageAppender: 'usage.gui'
error usageAppender1: 'usage.gui'
```

will only log `error` for `usage.gui`.

Comment: This sort of works: all `'usage.gui'` output goes to the right file. But everything else is still mixed up `'stdout'` and nothing is added to the `'application'` appender.

Comment: @GeneGolovchinsky Have a look at my update above. I streamlined it for ease to understand.

Comment: So to get multiple logging levels into a single appender, do I specify the least restrictive level (i.e., `TRACE`), and then control what actually gets logged by configuring the loggers?

Comment: I tried your updated suggestion, but the behavior remains unchanged: everything gets shoved into catalina.out, the usage.gui stuff gets into the right file, and the application.log receives no output.

Comment: Which level are you logging for `application.log`?

Comment: Can you show some sample code where you use loggers and attempting to use all of the appenders?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you don't see the log printing from src/groovy because some where else the higher Level ERROR set in the application. So if you set all the classes log to debug level then the logger debug is working.