# grails separating info logging

Tags: grails, logging, log4j

I am trying to separate the info, warn and errors log, i did the below configuration, but on info file continue to log the other types of log on the same file, i already tried to search on the other topics but i did not find a solution, anyone can help ?

```
def logLayoutPattern = new PatternLayout("%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS} %x %-5p %c{2} - %m%n")
appenders {
     appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(name: "perfil",threshold: Level.INFO,file: "/tmp/logs/file_perfil.log",datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",layout: logLayoutPattern)
     appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(name: "errors",threshold: Level.ERROR,file: "/tmp/logs/file_errors.log",datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",layout: logLayoutPattern)
     appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(name: "warn",threshold: Level.WARN,file: "/tmp/logs/file_warn.log",datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",layout: logLayoutPattern)
}

info perfil: ["grails.app.controllers.com.app.PerfilController"]
warn warn: 'grails.app'

error errors: ['org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',
       'org.springframework',
       'org.hibernate',
       'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate']
root {
    error 'errors'
    additivity = false
    warn 'warn'
    additivity = false
    info 'perfil'
    additivity = false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `additivity: false` on the custom appenders instead of the root logger.

Something like this would suffice:

```
info perfil: ["grails.app.controllers.com.app.PerfilController"]
     additivity: false

warn warn: 'grails.app'
     additivity: false

error errors: ['org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',
       'org.springframework',
       'org.hibernate',
       'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate']
     additivity: false

root {
    error 'errors'
    warn 'warn'
    info 'perfil'
}
```

All the loggers inherit from the root by default and additivity is true by default.

Comment: @paulo I suppose you do not need them in the root logger if you have the above setting. Can you remove the from root and see. I strongly believe that would be the setup. Will test it again when I get a chance. BTW what discrepancy do you see?

Comment: i tried removing the root block and tested but on this way nothing is recorded on logs even the messages that i put on controller. On the log that was supposed to appear only info logs appear warn and errors of the app.

Comment: @Paulo I think the 'warn' appender is overriding the 'perfil' appender because in both the cases you are looking to log `grails.app` package structure. Remove the `warn` appender and see how it behaves. I would have `perfil` only for `grails.app` which would take care of your controller `info` as well as `warn` logging.

Comment: i removed all configurations of 'warn' but it is still loggin warn, i do not know what i am doing wrong, on controller i am loading log like this 'private static final log = LogFactory.getLog("perfil")'
but if i load other log on other controller it log on the same file even if i create other appender

Comment: @paulo You do not need to create a `log` in controller, it is available as 'log' by default.

Comment: even without creating a log it is on the same way

Comment: Refer [this question and my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894504/grails-log4j-diffrerent-appenders-according-files), he made it work appropriately. You need to model after him. @Paulo